Is there a way to approximate this sum in $O(n\log n)$
I am trying to approximate (or get the concrete expression) of a function which is expressed as this sum
$$f(x) = \sum \limits_{i=0}^{100\,000} \frac{a_i x}{-b_i x + c_i}$$
Expanding this expression out results in a $100\,000$ degree rational function, which is computationally unrealistic to create or use, as the terms explode past floating point limits, $x$ only needs to be in the range from $0$ to $1$, and I know that the constants will be such that
$$f(x) <100\,000 \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq d \leq 1$$
Ideally, I would like to be able to plug in and get concrete values in $O(1)$, but anything less than $O(n)$ would work.
Also i considered using FFT to create the function but the problem of exploding terms still arises and constructing it would be $O(n(\log n)^2)$, and using it would still be $O(n)$.

You do t need to say $<O(n\log n)$ because $O(\cdot)$ already implies $<$.

Should we think of the sequences $(a_i)_i$, $(b_i)_i$, and $(c_i)_i$ as fixed or rarely changing and $x$ as changing frequently?  (I.e., is it acceptable to do some sort of precomputation on these sequences of coefficients, which precomputation can be used repeatedly for some set of $x$s?)

Yes, a, b, c are all known, but completely arbitrary, i.e. there is no pattern as i changes. x is the variable and yes this is what I want to change frequently, I want the output of the function for many different x.

@ThomasAndrews i wanted to explicitly say that I needed something faster than O(nlogn)

There is a risk that $-b_i x + c_i \approx 0$, causing out of range problems.  How do you want to handle that?

replace $a,b$ with their approximate distribution, and integrate

@user619894 how does one integrate over a distribution?

What is your $n$, is it the number of terms? Then the $O(n)$ method is straightforward, why do you need $O(n\log n)$ methods?

@EricTowers you're right I guess there is really no way to avoid that, however I don't need answers for those x, so is there no way to see approximate/test if an x will result in something really big.

@Yimin i need to test multiple x values, specifically binary search over x as the function is strictly increasing (up to some point), hence the O(nlogn) i currently know of.

I see, so you have stored $O(n)$ evaluations for some $x$ values drawn from $[0, 1]$ and try to use that to evaluate another $x$. Then you do not need binary search if those $x$ values are not randomly chosen, if $x$ values are equally spaced, then you can access the nearest one in O(1) time instead of $\log n$.

No sorry for the confusion I don't have the evaluations already.

Assuming that the degeneracies that Eric Towers pointed out are avoided for the range of $a,b,c$ in question, it seems that these would be fairly smooth objects which could be uniformly approximated by polynomials on $[0,1]$ (or really, any reasonable family of Stone-Weierstrass basis functions).  Then you don't get any combinatorial explosion when adding the 100000 approximants together.  Seems like you would have some freedom to adjust the degree to trade accuracy vs cost, and you could use different degrees for each $i$ to account for higher variability depending on the coefficients.

@ThomasAndrews: I disagree: $O(n\log n)$ doesn't imply $<O(n\log n)$. That is what $o(n\log n)$ is for.

You can rewrite $\frac{a_i x}{-b_i x + c_i}$ as $-\frac{a_i}{b_i}+\frac{a_ib_i}{-b_ix+c_i}$, reducing $f(x)$ to an expression of the form $u+\sum_i\frac{1}{v_ix+w_i}$.

No, $o(n\log n)$ is a limit thing. $f(n)=O(g(n))$ iff there is a $C$ with $f(n)\leq Cg(n)$ for all $n.$ You can pick a bigger $C$ and make it strictly $<$. The whole point of $O(\cdot)$ is that it is an upper bound. @TonyK If OP meant something else, then big-O is,not the appropriate notation.'

Are the $a$s, $b$s, and $c$s real, complex, something else?

@ThomasAndrews: That is not what $<O(\cdot)$ means, in my opinion. $O(\cdot)$ is not a function, it's a shorthand, and $<O(\cdot)$ means precisely the same as $o(\cdot)$. In view of this disagreement, perhaps your edit was unwarranted.

And yet, there is no assigned meaning of $<O(),$ @TonyK. It is made up notation. What the OP meant is unclear. Correcting me, rather than OP, was a waste of your and my time.

@ThomasAndrews: Your very first comment implies that $<O(\cdot)$ does have an assigned meaning, surely? And you are not being forced to waste your time by responding :-)

First, As you didn't quite define $n$, I assume the sum is actually $I_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i x\over c_i-b_i x}$, and you are asking for fast approximations  for large $n$, and 100,000 was an example.
What I propose is to "bin" the $a_i, b_i, c_i$ triplets into a histogram, and approximate it by a smooth distribution $nP(a,b,c)$, and then write $I_n(x)=n\int \mathrm{d}a\ \mathrm{d}b\ \mathrm{d}c\ P(a,b,c){ax \over c-bx} $. The integration over $a,b,c$ is a fixed time operation, so you have a one time cost of approximating $P$, and then $O(1)$ per $x$.
I have skimmed a lot of details since I don't know much about the $a,b,c$ distribution. For example, if it doesn't bin properly (very widely distributed), the smooth $P$ will be a bad approximation.
Edit
Motivated by @EricTowers solution below, we can get away with $P({a\over c}, {b \over c})$.

thank you I think I understand, one clarification is why is n multipling P, i understand why its to the left of the integral, but i dont understand why $nP(a,b,c)$ is the probability distribution.

$n$ is the number of points you have, assuming the distribution is normalized. The hypothesis is that in the large $n$ limit, the distribution converges to something.

$P(a,b,c)$ is a probability distribution, so the sum of the areas of the rectangles in its histogram is $1$, meaning each $a$, $b$, and/or $c$ is contributing $1/n$.  Since you want each to contribute $1$, you need to multiply the distribution by $n$ to convert to the counting histogram.

Framing challenge: Computing the full rational expression (symbolically) and using that to evaluate $f$ is not totally unreasonable, if you have a symbolic calculator.  The result won't be worse than degree $10^5$ over degree $10^5$, so involves ${}<10^6$ floating point multiplies and adds per evaluation, which should be on the order of a millisecond on vaguely current computer hardware.  Alternatively, you may not have access to a symbolic calculator, or you may be trying to do this on smaller/weaker hardware, or (panic!) by hand.
Let $\varepsilon$ be the maximum absolute error in $f(x)$ you will tolerate.
Construct a sorted list of $c_i/b_i$ that are in $[0,d]$.  For any $x$ on this list, $f(x)$ is undefined.  So a first test in evaluating $f$ is to check if $x$ is on this list and do whatever is appropriate in your environment to report that $f(x)$ is undefined.  We will call members of this list "undefineds".  For searching in this list, we imagine a binary search with two "fingers" in the list, the terminal state of which has both fingers pointing to the same undefined (corresponding to $x$ being that $c_i/b_i$) or both fingers pointing to adjacent elements of the list (corresponding to $x$ lying in the interval bounded by those two undefineds).
Case 1: None of the undefineds are in $[0,d]$. Construct the Taylor series for each term in the sum, centered at $d/2$.
$$  \frac{-d a_i}{d b_i - 2 c_i} + \frac{2 a_i c_i}{b_i(d b_i - 2 c_i)}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^k b_i^k}{(d b_i - 2 c_i)^k}\left(x - \frac{d}{2}\right)^k $$
(Note that from the $k^{\text{th}}$ coefficient, we get the $k+1^{\text{th}}$ coefficient by multiplying by the constant $2b_i/(db_i-2c_i)$.)
Iterating $i$, accumulate the coefficients in each degree of $(x - d/2)$.  For each $i$, use the remainder estimate to determine the degree bound to get the error in that Taylor series less than $\varepsilon/10^5$.  (Note that this means either a first pass just to get the degree bound and a second pass to accumulate the coefficients, or a single pass, but every time the degree bound increases, back-filling the coefficients in the new degrees that were not accumulated the first time.  It can be a good idea to accumulate coefficients in "chunks" (say, multiples of ten) so that you usually have a few extra coefficients accumulated than your degree limit requires.  Then at the end, either drop unneeded coefficients or keep them -- the difference in compute time will be small.)  At the end you get the coefficients of a Taylor series for $f$ centered at $d/2$, which you can quickly evaluate with powers of $x-d/2$.
Case 2: A "few" of the undefineds are in $[0,d]$.  Suppose that $i$ is such that $0 \leq c_i/b_i \leq d$.  Then use the procedure for Case 1, but do not accumulate the $i^{\text{th}}$ term (because it's Taylor series is only convergent for the portion of $[0,d]$, split by $c_i/b_i$ containing $d/2$).  Instead, to a different list of terms, append $(a_i, b_i, c_i)$.  When evaluating $f(x)$, compute the Taylor series as in Case 1, then for each $i$ where $c_i/b_i$ is in $[0,d]$, accumulate $a_i x/(c_i - b_i x)$.  That is, we gather the "good terms" into the Taylor series, and leave the "bad terms" unchanged.
The cut-off value of "few" in Case 2 depends on how much you really feel like implementing subsequent cases and how often $x \approx c_i/b_i$ (that is, one of the terms in $f(x)$ is approximately dividing by zero).
Case 3: "Many" of the undefineds are in $[0,d]$ but the $x$s are not close to the undefineds.  The sorted list of undefineds gives a partition of $[0,d]$ into intervals whose boundaries are undefineds.  For each interval, accumulate the Taylor series as in Case 1, but centered at the middle of that interval.  With $m$ the middle of the interval, the series for a term of $f$ is
$$  \frac{-m a_i}{m b_i - c_i} + \frac{a_i c_i}{b_i(m b_i - c_i)}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_i^k}{(m b_i - c_i)^k}\left(x - m \right)^k $$
(Note that we expect each interval to be "small", and $|x-m|$ is bounded by half the width of the interval, so the powers of $x-m$ get tiny fast.  It may be prudent in evaluating the Taylor series for $x$s in this interval to add the terms in decreasing order of degree (to preserve rounding produced by the tiny terms that percolates up to the large terms that is lost when you add in the other order).)  Evaluating $f$ proceeds by looking up $x$ on the list of undefineds.  Each undefined (except $x=d$, if $f(d)$ is undefined) is the left endpoint of an interval and we associate that undefined with the Taylor series for that interval and use it to evaluate $f(x)$.
Case 4:  "Many" of the undefineds are in $[0,d]$ and the $x$s are frequently close to the $c_i/b_i$.  Now we mix the approaches in Case 2 and Case 3.  For each $c_i/b_i \in [0,d]$, we construct the Taylor series for $f(x)$ omitting the $i^{\text{th}}$ term, which we evaluate as $a_i x/(c_i -b_i x)$ (more or less constructing the Laurent expansion for $f$ centered at $c_i/b_i$).  For the intervals between the undefineds, we construct Taylor series as in Case 3.  To evaluate, we search through our list of undefineds -- either $f(x)$ is undefined or it lies in the interval $(c_i/b_i, c_j/b_j)$ containing the midpoint $m$.  Determine whether $x$ is closest to $c_i/b_i$, $m$, or $c_j/b_j$ (with ties resolved however you like).  If it is closer to an endpoint, use the Laurent series for that endpoint, otherwise use the Taylor series for the midpoint.  (Note: With the change in evaluation method at the 1/4 and 3/4 points along each interval, you might notice small discontinuities at those points.  A way to address that is to linearly interpolate between the closest centered Laurent and closest centered Taylor series -- 100% Taylor series at a midpoint to 0% at an endpoint and vice versa for the Laurent series.  It doubles the computation time, but eliminates these discontinuities.)
Note: The above is written as if the $c_i/b_i$ are all distinct.  In cases 1 and 2, it does not matter if there are repeated undefineds.  In cases 3 and 4, coincident $c_i/b_i$ just result in extra terms of the original series.  If one insists that these be normalized to a single object, the actual (complete) Laurent series of a term is
$$  \frac{-a_ic_i}{b_i^2}\left(x - \frac{c_i}{b_i}\right)^{-1} - \frac{a_i}{b_i}  $$
and one can accumulate coefficients of these by degrees to compress the contributions from coincident undefineds into a single Laurent series.  It's also easy to treat all the series in cases 1 through 4 as Laurent series by making the $(x-m)^{-1}$ coefficient be zero for Taylor series.
The precomputation can be extensive (depending on how many intervals $[0,d]$ is partitioned into).  But once it's all done, the search through the undefineds to determine which series to use to evaluate $f$ requires $O(\log_2 10^5)$ comparisons.  Then the evaluation is a few multiples and adds (depending on the cutoff degrees for the series -- for which we would need to know much more about the $a$s, $b$s, and $c$s to estimate the operation count).

will the Taylors converge beyond the distance to the pole?

@user619894 : Of course not.  That's why we need to get the list of poles (undefineds) and only put Taylor series on the intervals between them.
